# Two same tikzpictures in the same document: Package pgfkeys Error

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{caption}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
      \usetikzlibrary{fit}
      \node[draw,fill=blue,rectangle] (v1) at (0,0) {$v_1$}   ;  
      \node[draw,fill=red,circle] (v2) at (2,0) {$v_2$} ;  
      \draw[<-] (v1) to (v2) ;  
      \node[draw,rectangle,very thick,fit=(v1) (v2)] (rec) {  }   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure 1}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
      \usetikzlibrary{fit}
      \node[draw,fill=blue,rectangle] (v1) at (0,0) {$v_1$}   ;  
      \node[draw,fill=red,circle] (v2) at (2,0) {$v_2$} ;  
      \draw[<-] (v1) to (v2) ;  
      \node[draw,rectangle,very thick,fit=(v1) (v2)] (rec) {  }   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure 2}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the above tex code, Figure 2 is an exact copy of Figure 1.
When I comment out Figure 2, the code compiles normally.
However, when I include Figure 2 in the code, the compiler complains with the following error message:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/fit', to which you
>   passed '(v1) (v2)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
>   misspelled it. [...e[draw,rectangle,very thick,fit=(v1) (v2)]]

Why does this happens how can I correct this?

Comment: You wrote `\end{tikzpictur}` a final "e" is missing

Comment: ... and move (both) `\usetikzlibrary{fit}` to the preamble of the document.

Comment: Moving \usetikzlibrary{fit} to the preamble solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Schrödinger's cat commented, moving `\usetikzlibrary{fit}` to the preamble solved the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{caption}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
      \node[draw,fill=blue,rectangle] (v1) at (0,0) {$v_1$}   ;  
      \node[draw,fill=red,circle] (v2) at (2,0) {$v_2$} ;  
      \draw[<-] (v1) to (v2) ;  
      \node[draw,rectangle,very thick,fit=(v1) (v2)] (rec) {  }   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure 1}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round,>=latex]
      \node[draw,fill=blue,rectangle] (v1) at (0,0) {$v_1$}   ;  
      \node[draw,fill=red,circle] (v2) at (2,0) {$v_2$} ;  
      \draw[<-] (v1) to (v2) ;  
      \node[draw,rectangle,very thick,fit=(v1) (v2)] (rec) {  }   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Figure 2}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```